# Authorization token not binding in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm calling a REST api like so:

```
HttpClient client;
var uri = new Uri(Const.GetUserAccount);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("accessToken", App.AccessToken);
var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
```

And here is my action signature (accessToken is null):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetAccountAsync([FromHeader] string accessToken)
```

The token is in Request.Headers.HeaderAuthorization and its value is:

```
"accessToken" + a space + the guid
```

That seems odd. Shouldn't there be a name value pair? Like:

"accessToken": "theGUID"

Is this why it's not binding? If so, how do I pass it correctly? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the parameter should be called authorization rather than accessToken

Comment: How will the `[FromHeader]` attribute know where to get accessToken from?

Comment: what is your token?? JWT?

Comment: No, it *shouldn't* be `"accessToken": "theGUID"` - The whole header is actually `Authorization: accessToken theGUID`. The `:` demarcates the header/value pair. As @CamiloTerevinto states, you can change the parameter to `authorization`, which will give you a value of `accessToken theGUID`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is this why it's not binding?

The reason is that your action method expects a `accessToken` from request headers :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetAccountAsync([FromHeader] string accessToken)
```

While you there's no such a `AccessToken: xxx_yyy_zzz` header in the request .

If you send a request as below :

```
GET https://localhost:44323/api/values/account HTTP/1.1
accessToken : xxx_yyy_zzz
```

The ModelBinder will bind the `accessToken`.

> If so, how do I pass it correctly?

I'm not sure why you want to get the `accessToken` within an action method . However , if you do need the access token by model binding , there're at least two ways to do that :

One way to do that is to change your action method to get the `Authorization` header directly:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetAccount2Async([FromHeader] string authorization) 
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization)) { /* */ }
    if (!authorization.StartsWith("accessToken",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) { /* */ }

    var token = authorization.Substring("accessToken".Length).Trim();
    // ...
}
```

It will works when you send a request with a header of `Authorization : accessToken xxx_yyy_zzz` .

However , the approach above is not nice and clean . A better way is to create a custom `ModelBinder` .

Firstly Let's create a dummy class to hold the accessToken value :

```
public class AccessTokenAuthorizationHeader
{
    public string TokenValue { get; set; }
}
```

And here's a simple model binder that will retrieve access token from headers :

```
public class AuthorizationHeaderBinder : IModelBinder
{
    const string DEFAULT_ACCESS_TOKEN_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX = "accessToken";
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext)); }

        var modelName = bindingContext.BinderModelName;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelName)) { modelName = DEFAULT_ACCESS_TOKEN_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX; }

        var authorization = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault();
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authorization)) {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        if (!authorization.StartsWith(modelName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        var token = authorization.Substring(modelName.Length).Trim();

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(new AccessTokenAuthorizationHeader() {
            TokenValue =token,
        });
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Lastly ,  decorate the previous `AccessTokenAuthorizationHeader` with a `ModelBinderAttribute`:

```
[ModelBinder(BinderType =typeof(AuthorizationHeaderBinder))]
public class AccessTokenAuthorizationHeader
{
    public string TokenValue { get; set; }
}
```

And now we can bind it automatically :

```
[HttpGet("Account3")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetAccount3Async(AccessTokenAuthorizationHeader accessToken) {
    var result =new JsonResult(accessToken?.TokenValue);
    return result;
}
```

Let's test it with a requset :

```
GET https://localhost:44323/api/values/account3 HTTP/1.1
Authorization : accessToken 111111
```

The response will be :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpccmVwb3J0XDIwMThcOVw5LTEzXFNPLkF1dGhvcml6YXRpb25IZWFkZXJcQXBwXEFwcFxhcGlcdmFsdWVzXGFjY291bnQz?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 13 Sep 2018 01:54:25 GMT

"111111"
```

Comment: You can also access the headers via `HttpContext.Request.Headers` from any action method.  No need for custom binding.

Comment: @Brad Well , that's exactly what I did  in the first approach .However ,  if in that case , you have to validate whether the header of `Authorization`   is null or empty , whether it's `Authorization : accessToken xxx_yyy_zzz` or `Authorization : access-Token xxx_yyy_zzz` or something else . And if there're mutilple action methods that need the accessToken , I'm sure our heads will hurt .

Comment: You might want to use ModelBinding so unit tests are easier.  You can pass in a string directly on the method call vs. having to setup a context, a request, a headers collection and the actual header name/value.  Sure you `can` do all of that in `every` unit test and `every controller method` but why not write it once and reuse it everywhere?

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns Thanks for your suggestion. But could you please elaborate a little more ？I do create a ModelBinder in my second approach.

Comment: My comment was mostly toward @Brad whose approach would require you to setup a lot of extra cruft for every unit test.