# Any added headers to DefaultRequestHeaders will not make it through to the API

Tags: c#, post, postman, httpclient, .net-5

In my API project I have the following controller that works fine when called with Postman:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload([FromHeader] string authorization, IFormFile payLoad) { ... }
```

When I use Postman, I add a string (Token) in the Auth section and specify the Type as Bearer Token. I then go to the Body section and set the Key `payLoad` as a **File** and choose a file to upload.

Postman generates C# - RestSharp code as follows:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:11764/api/logdata");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer exampleTokenString");
request.AddFile("payLoad", "/C:/path/oqwi.zip");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

I'm not using RestSharp so I haven't verified that the code above works *but* the Postman post itself within the tool works fine and my API gets all the data as I would expect.

In a separate client application, whenever I attempt to make a `POST` call, the API controller (at the top of this page) always receives `null` for the `authorization` parameter. The file loads in fine. Here is the client code trying to `POST` to the API with every example I attempted to add the header **(I did not try them all at once)**:

```
Uri EndPoint = new Uri("http://localhost:11764/api/logdata");
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
        = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, EndPoint)
    {
        Content = fileAsFormData
    };

    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);

    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    ...
```

*Note: The above is an example of every different attempt I made at adding the authorization and token; I didn't do all of the above at once.*

I have inspected the object in the client during runtime and it appears as if the header(s) are added on where I would expect them to be. Using Fiddler, I can confirm this:

[image]

---

**UPDATE:** I've tried adding other headers, like CacheControl, and none of them make it through to the API. I see it on the client side during runtime, I see it in Fiddler, but then they're all scrubbed by the time they get to the API. I'm wondering if this Github discussion has anything to do with it:

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/26475

Comment: Why are you trying to add the Autorization header 4 times?

Comment: @phuzi I made two separate remarks about this in my original post. I did not add it 4 times.

Comment: Are you running something like Fiddler to see what is actually being sent?

Comment: @phuzi I am, and I can see the Authorization header. Ill post a screenshot

Comment: Try `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your token");`

Comment: Fiddler screenshot confirm it's not a problem with the client. It must be with the API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authorization token not binding in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52304246/authorization-token-not-binding-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: @phuzi No, that author's issue was they were calling their parameter "accessToken" and not "authorization", so there were binding issues. Im not sure the problem is with the API, because when I POST this with Postman, the API gets the authorization token.

Comment: @JohnWu That doesn't work either; still comes in as `null` from the API.

Comment: Do you see any differences between the Postman and client requests in Fiddler?

Comment: No. On the API side, I tried stripping the `[FromHeader]` command and then just observing the `HttpContext.Request.Headers` within the controller and the Authorization is definitely not there. So weird that I can inspect it in the client on the way out, see it in Fiddler, but then when it gets to the API it's totally gone.

Comment: You can confirm whether the header is present by adding it to the IIS logs (be sure to remove it afterward). If you find with certainty that the header is being sent but not received, the only answer is that it is being removed in between, e.g. by a proxy or firewall of some kind.

Comment: @JohnWu I think updates in Core 2.1 may relate to this issue I am experiencing here, but I cant see a workaround https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/26475

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [Github ticket](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/26475) within the dotnet runtime team,

> karelz commented on Oct 24, 2018 •
> FYI: 2 weeks ago we released a security fix to remove Authorization request headers from redirects.

Thinking that redirects may be at the heart of the issue, by using Fiddler or the Visual Studio inspection tool, I was able to observe that the callback to my client was from `https://localhost:5001`. I was not expecting this...

When I was constructing the original client code to `POST` to my API, I was simply copying all of the values I had used when I was exercising these calls from Postman. As an example from Postman's C# RestSharp:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:11764/api/logdata");
```

This ultimately was a red herring caused by the intelligent way Postman handles redirects. Postman was indeed posting to `http://localhost:11764` -- but then getting a secure redirect to `https://localhost:5001`. Postman would then subtly resend the original request with reattached headers to this new secure endpoint.

So after updating the endpoint that the client will `POST` to, from `http://localhost:11764/api/logdata` to `https://localhost:5001/api/logdata`, everything works as expected.

But why `https://localhost:5001`? It's setup this way in (most) `launchSettings.json`:

```
"MyProj.UploadApi.WebApi": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": false,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:11764"
}
```